# SQL query to join two tables and get data?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables a,b.

Table `table1` has 5 columns:

```
  primary key AS pkid
  table2_primary-key AS id1
  table2_primary-key AS id2 
  rating
  date
```

Table `table2` has 2 columns:

```
 primary key AS pkid
 name
```

I want join table1 to table2 and display the primary key, rating, and date from table1, and names that correspond to `table1.id1` and `table1.id2`.

For that I wrote the following query

```
Select 
  a.pkid
  , b.name
  , c.name
  , a.rating
  , a.date
FROM table1 a, table2 b, table2 c
WHERE a.id1=b.pkid and a.id2=c.pkid;
```

Is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: Well... you have **two** foreign keys, so you need **two** joins.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better experience if you
take moment to take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can
also read about asking a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an
attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your query is essentially good. I would improve two aspects:

- Use modern join syntax.
- If the foreign keys (id1 and id2) are nullable (you don't say) I would use outer joins.

The modified version of your query would look like:

```
select
  a.pkid, b.name, 
  case when c.name is null then 'system' else c.name end,
  a.rating, a.date
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.id1 = b.pkid
left join table2 c on a.id2 = c.pkid
```

Comment: Yes table1 id1 not billable but id2 some times zero on that time I want display name as system

Comment: @Ramya that's a pretty important piece of business logic you left out of your question.

Comment: @Ramya As requested, I added a `CASE` clause to transform a null id2-name to 'system',

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 1):

You'll always need the two joins (since id1 and id2 are different)...

However, I'd use an explicit join instead of a comma. As such

```
SELECT A.PKID, B.NAME, C.NAME, A.RATING, A.NAME
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ID1=B.PKID
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 C ON A.ID2=C.PKID;
```